# The reconnection feature is not working in my Socket.io implementation

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I'm having issues with Socket.io's automatic reconnection feature.
I'm using Angular on the frontend and Express on the backend.
From what I understand, Socket.io has automatic reconnection built-in, meaning there is no need for additional configuration (I've tested it in another project and it works, but not in this one).
My WebSocket service looks like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WebSocketService {
  socket: Socket;
  // readonly url: string = 'ws://localhost:3000';
  readonly url: string = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(this.url, {
      reconnection: true,
      reconnectionDelay: 1000, // Tiempo inicial de espera para reconectar (en milisegundos)
      reconnectionAttempts: Infinity, // Número máximo de intentos de reconexión
      timeout: 5000,
    });
    
  }
```

I also tried removing the object from the second parameter in the constructor's io() function, but it doesn't work, and I tried to add the property forceNew: true. If I stop the backend server and start it again, the socket doesn't reconnect (I have console.log() statements in my backend code to check this), as shown here:

```
this.io.on("connection", (socket: Socket) => {
            socket.on("enviarId", (mensaje: any) => {
                const mensajeRecibido = new SocketMensaje(mensaje.destinos, mensaje.payload);
                console.log("Se conecto el socket ", socket.id);
                
                this.saveUserId(mensajeRecibido.getPayload().uuidUsuario, socket.id);
            })

            socket.on("disconnect", () => {
                console.log("Se desconecto el socket ", socket.id);
            })
        });
```

Additionally, I'm getting another annoying error in my console that I'm not sure why it's occurring and I haven't been able to trace it:

```
zone.js:2707 
 GET http://localhost:4200/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OYCNCFc 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask    @   zone.js:2707
scheduleTask    @   zone.js:393
onScheduleTask  @   zone.js:283
scheduleTask    @   zone.js:386
scheduleTask    @   zone.js:221
scheduleMacroTask   @   zone.js:244
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone    @   zone.js:683
...
```